# Excel INDEX MATCH across 2 sheets & Update data with VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, spreadsheet

I would like some help with the following tasks.

1. I will in the future add an additional sheet with 3 columns. A would be a date, B a Wo number and C would be the date which the Wo was closed by looking up the date closed and Wo number from the sheet titled Graph data. There are blanks in that row so the formula would need to skip blanks.
2. I manually input data tables into the sheet titled Graph data, at the column titled Wo, the columns to the left contain formula to return a few specific words or dates. What I need is a formula which would look for duplicate Wo numbers in the column above the data I have just put in and then delete that row. This is to update the status, date closed and any other associated data with the Wo numbers.

EDIT; happy to share the workbook if required

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Since you want to delete WO Number so better use a Helper Column using `IF(Countif(,,,,))` to find Duplicate WO Numbers then Filter & Delete is one method Second is use MACRO to delete Duplicates in WO Number Column. Better make it Clear that You want only to delete Duplicate WO numbers or entire Row/Rows having Duplicate WO number !!

Comment: Hi Rajesh, could you explain a little more please - putting ,,, doesn't help me out a great deal. Thanks in advance

Comment: ,, suppose you have WO numbers in Col A the write this `=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A1)>1, "Duplicate","")` in adjacent Column and fill down. Then apply Auto Filter and Filter Duplicate and then Delete Rows.

Comment: Better create Chat room and invite me to continue the discussion ! ☺

Comment: @DanielBridges, Careful filling down with the above comment. Doing so will not *"look for duplicate Wo numbers in the column above the data [you] have just put in"*. Instead the first distinct column working downward will not be marked duplicate and everything after that, including the row just added, will be marked a duplicate, and if following the instructions in the comment above, deleted. Thus the row just added will be deleted.

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a good start, but I would like to make it as automatic as possible. A macro would be a cool idea. The WO are in column D, related data runs to the right. BTW the data is then used in multiple pivot tables to create a dashboard at the end of the workbook for analysis

Comment: @Ted, so you are saying the formula suggested would in effect delete the newest WO and it's row of data. That would be the opposite of what I need. I need the updated data to stay in place of the old

Comment: @DanielBridges That is exactly what I am saying. The normal approach is to keep the first occurence and get rid of the rest. However, your OP specifically stated you wanted the older duplicate rows above the just added row to be removed, so I wanted you to be aware of this oversight.

Comment: Ted, are you able to suggest s solution to my problems?

Comment: Be sure your workbook is backed up when testing a macro. Macros in general cannot be undone with control-Z, in fact it is my experience the whole undo buffer is wiped and reset after performing row deletions with a macro.

Comment: @DanielBridges, let me say how the `If(Counif(,,,,))` Formula works. Suppose WO Num `1` in Cell `A1` and in `A5', A7, A10 & in A15` then as soon you copy down the Formula, will return `Duplicate` for `A5, A7, A10 and A15`  since are Duplicates in Column. And then after if you Filter Duplicates to Delete Row `A5, A7,A10 & A15` will be removed. *So that I have written decide first what U wanna to Delete ONLY DUPLICATE WO nums in Col or Rows !!*

Comment: If there is a previous instance of the WO number found in the WO column then the row number containing the previous WO would be removed in its entirety. Or the row data gets transposed into the previous and the new gets deleted. Data refresh is the key outcome relative to the WO number

Comment: @RajeshS, Read the OP, it is saying to identify duplicates **above** the row of data entered and mark that data for deletion. This is the opposite of the standard top down approach you have suggested.

Comment: @TedD., what I mean was after settle down with new data entry the show Formula can be use for any range either Above of Below even. Since OP's Screen Shot doesn't provides clear picture !!

Comment: Happy to share the workbook

Comment: I could really do with some assistance in this, any one willing? The workbook is available here https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1268616-index-match-ignore-blanks-and-update-data-in-rows-if-1-cell-matches.html

Comment: Somebody has kindly written this piece of VBA; Option Explicit
Dim Findstr As String, x As Double, choice As VbMsgBoxResult

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Findstr = Target.Value
For x = 2 To Target.Row - 1
If ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 4) = Findstr Then
choice = MsgBox("DUPLICATE 'WO' EXISTS AT ROW " & x & vbCrLf & "DO YOU WISH TO DELETE PREVIOUS RECORD", vbYesNo + vbInformation)
If choice = vbNo Then Exit Sub
Rows(x).Delete
Exit Sub
End If
Next x
End Sub

Comment: But it only works if I manually type in the values. I paste in a set of data every morning. Can anyone on here advise how to make it work when pasting?